Oracle. Procedures. Beginner. How to handle large string inputs? (CLOB)
I new to using Oracle, so I could really use the help.
I have a procedure:
create or replace procedure Demo_Name
    (someId IN number default null,
    planShapes IN string,
    OutputCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) is
planShape st_geometry;
begin
   IF(planShapes is not null) THEN
       planShape :=  sde.st_geomfromtext(planShapes, 2039);
   ELSE planShape := null;
   end If;
OPEN OutputCursor for
    select distinct
    p.name as "name"
    from table p

    where (someId is not null)
        and (planShape is null or (sde.st_envintersects(p.SHAPE, planShape) = 1 and sde.st_intersects(p.SHAPE, planShape) = 1));
end Demo_Name;

Only when the size of the text is bigger than the size of the string I get the error: ora-20004 error generating shape from text
The issue is that planShapes can't handle the amount of characters that this parameter may get. So I tried changing the type.So far, I tried to change planShape's type to: VARCHAR2 and CLOB with no luck.
VARCHAR2 got me the same error.
CLOB didn't get an error number but I did run into an issue:
When Testing with CLOB type: it won't regeister the input and remains empty.
I don't want to work with arrays, because I know for sure that the input should be contained inside a single clob.
I don't know how to solve this issue. What type should I use? Is there any reason why CLOB shouldn't work?

According to the doc sde.st_geomfromtext takes a CLOB, so the problem is either the  srid parameter either the content of the clob.

sde.st_geomfromtext also works with a string (as proven when I take a polygon that can be fully contained in the string). From this, I must deduct that the problem is the clob and not the id.

For example, look at the examples in: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-geomfromtext.html

The API defines the parameter as a CLOB so anything ORACLE can convert implicitly to a CLOB will be accepted, so if you are sure the problem is not the id, call the procedure with "empty_clob() || the_polygon_definition_fitting_in_a_string" and compare.

I can't find the empty_clob() function or should I just leave it empty?

EMPTY_CLOB() is quite old (seen since 2001 in forums...), which version are you running ?

Ok, so I copied a string value that previously worked when the type was string. Pasted it in the clob input in the test, but still got the whole line colored yellow (no other indication for an error)

pl/sql 14.0.5.1986, oci v 12.1, client dll: 12.2.0

"got the whole line colored yellow" - what does that mean; how are you testing it and providing the value? Does PL/SQL Developer know you're trying to supply a CLOB, or is it perhaps assuming a VARCHAR2 and complaining because the value is too big? (It certainly seems to be an issue with the client side, not the procedure, anyway...)

I'm right-clicking on the procedure, then choose test. In the window that opens, I add the someId parameter, then I click on the three dots at the right end of the planShapes line, another window opens. I paste the string there, save it, close the window. Press F8 to run the procedure. the line of planShapes will then be colored yellow. The type of planShapes is CLOB through all of that.

Just a side-note, When I'm in the Test window, if I change the planShapes  type from CLOB to Temporary CLOB this works

I managed to use the EMPTY_CLOB() function, I still get the line yellowed, but the still works when I press on the cursor outputcursor.

Please remove the “oracle-spatial” and add an ESRI and SDE tagS instead.

I can't add the SDE tag because it isn't listed as a possibility.
